# PyPDF2 hyperlink box working when pdf opened in browser, but not when opened in Preview/Adobe

Tags: python, pypdf

See code below. The hyperlink box object appears when the pdf is opened in a browser, but it does not appear when the file is downloaded and opened in Preview/Adobe. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

```
# !pip install PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from PyPDF2.generic import RectangleObject as ro

reader = PdfReader('filename.pdf')
writer = PdfWriter()

for page in reader.pages:
    writer.add_page(page)

# Make a black rectangle in the bottom-left corner with the link
writer.add_uri(
    page_number=0,
    uri="https://github.com/",
    rect=ro([280, 10, 302, 20]),
    border = 'dott'
)
output = open('filename2.pdf','wb')
writer.write(output)
output.close()
# files.download('filename2.pdf')
```

Comment: tested on _Atril Document Viewer_ and Firefox, both working. Maybe is because you are using a preview? Have you tested with other pdfs with hyperlinks generated for ex by LaTeX?

Comment: @cards yes it works in the firefox browser - that's the browser I use as well. I haven't tested with other pdfs with hyperlinks. I'm trying to use this to create a resume pdf. And I'd imagine most viewing a resume pdf would be using Preview or Adobe.

Comment: I don't have installed neither Adobe nor Preview  so I cannot help much. I would say test with other pdfs to investigate if the issue depends on how the pdf is generated. Try with a [latex](https://latexbase.com/d/6ba0d79b-1577-41ed-8dd4-48ea4a8375ed) one